# Need to to search and replace within a file 2 times, would prefer to be able to do it once iteratively

Tags: regex, awk, sed, replace

Question is phrased oddly, sorry about that.

So I have a CSV file with a ton of data, but in certain places I have no data and thus a ",," or even ",,," with two consecutive null pieces of data, or more, such as ",,,,."

Now, I need *something* between each comma. And I can easily do a search and replace with sed:

```
sed s/,,/,-,/g < testfile
```

The problem is that 2+ consecutive nulls force me to run sed twice to replace everything, since ",,," is turned into ",-,," on the first pass, and only ",-,-," on the second pass.

Note that 2 passes will properly convert all null entries in the entire fall. However, I don't like that because it feels clunky. Is there a way to do all of my replacements with 1 command?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give `perl` a chance then you can use lookahead feature and use:

```
perl -pe 's/,(?=,)/,-/g' file
```

Alternatively you can use `awk`:

```
echo ",,," | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=2; i<NF; i++) if ($i=="") $i="-"} 1'
,-,-,
```

Comment: That awk script does not work correctly. It does not preserve internal fields correctly. It needs `if (!$i)` added.

Answer (score 3):

You can get sed to loop until it doesn't need to anymore:

```
sed ':a;s/,,/,-,/g;ta'
```

Explanation:

- `:a` - create a label
- `s///` - perform the required substitution
- `ta` - If a s/// has done a successful substitution since the last input  line was read and since the last t or T command, then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.

So that script will loop over each line until `,,` doesn't match anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/,,/,-,/g;s/,,/,-,/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo ',,,' | awk '{while(gsub(/,,/,",-,"));}1'
,-,-,
```

`gsub()` returns the number of substitutions made on each invocation so the enclosing while loop terminates when that number is zero. So, it will loop no more than 2 times for this case.